# Can Xcode bots be run in a specified order

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have some projects that depend on other projects.  Once all the projects are built,  I'm okay until the next API change.  Then, if one of the downstream projects gets kicked off before an upstream project is built, it'll fail.

So, can you specify that bots for upstream projects get run before the downstream ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just post my own solution to this problem, though it's more like a hack.

Since the bots are run in alphabet/numerical order, you can number them like you used to do with your old BASIC programs.  And, like basic, you can run number them like 10,20, etc. in case you have to insert bots in between.

A little better would be to assign the same number to ones that could run concurrently.

I would love to see a better solution to this, but this would do the trick.